# in java use for loop not valid to use int

Tags: java, xml

i am try to create xml tree in using java.
i am totally fresher in JAVA.
i am find some code for this.

```
package ep;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class Tclass {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("products");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);
        for(int x = 1; x < 20; x = x+1) {
        // staff elements
        Element staff = doc.createElement("product_id");
        rootElement.appendChild(staff);

        // set attribute to staff element
        Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("value");

        // shorten way
        staff.setAttribute("value", x);
        }
        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("file.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("File saved!");

      } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

its work perfact.
but i am try to use for-loop on them to create multiple element then its return me error on line no.40
`The method setAttribute(String, String) in the type Element is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)` 
what's problem i do ? 
please help.
thanks...

Comment: thanks this is solve.... (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element#setAttribute(name,value)`, here this value is a simple `string`, it is not parsed as it is being set. So any markup (such as syntax to be recognized as an entity reference) is treated as literal text.

So use `String` as value instead of any other type. So convert your `int` value to string.

```
staff.setAttribute("value", Integer.toString(i)); // preferable as static
```

or

```
staff.setAttribute("value", new Integer(i).toString());
```

or

```
staff.setAttribute("value", ""+i);
```

or

```
staff.setAttribute("value", String.valueOf(i)); // preferable as static
```

Comment: can you post the new answer for get the random number for  `staff.setAttribute("value", random number here);`

Comment: like smile :) and i am use this `Random rand = new Random(); 
  int value = rand.nextInt(50); 
  
  
  // shorten way
  tab_id.setAttribute("value", ""+value);`but i want to start 20 to 50. its start 0 to 50

Comment: you can keep `Random rand = new Random();` this line out of your loop.

Comment: sorry this is not work perfect i want to change range this like 0 to 50 i want b/w 20 to 50

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

```
staff.setAttribute("value", x);
```

replace by:

```
staff.setAttribute("value", ""+x);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your are passing in an `int` while it's expecting a `String` .

```
 staff.setAttribute("value", String.valueOf(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

you should replace

```
staff.setAttribute("value", x);
```

with

```
staff.setAttribute("value", String.valueOf(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `for()-loop` with the following `for(Integer x = 1; x < 20; x = x+1)` and now in the function

```
staff.setAttribute("value", x.toString());
```